JavaBuilder error - 'substitutedVariableInterfaces' is null
I'm migrating a Java 8 Maven project to Java 21 using the latest Eclipse IDE version (2024-03). Although I can compile with maven and run the maven targets without any problems, I cannot build the project in Eclipse using "Build Project". The Maven project is imported as an existing Maven project and looks fine so far.
The error message is:

"Errors occurred during build. Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'myproject'. Cannot read array length because 'substitutedVariableInterfaces' is null".

Because the Java Builder stops parsing the code, I cannot use the editor as intended. No jumping to classes, finding imports, and everything else. It is like a text editor with syntax highlighting ;)
The question is, what is the problem and can I solve it?
I already tried:

new workspace with new pulled code
different Eclipse version (2023-12)
without additional plugins
with a small set of our standard plugins
Tried several Java 21 versions (oracle, openjdk)
tried Java 17
started Eclipse with Java 21 instead of the bundled Java
had a colleague do the same (with same result - same error message)
used IntelliJ (the project is working here!)


Please provide a minimal example reproducible with the current Eclipse version (2024-03) without any additional plugin and a fresh workspace. Show the complete error message: in the Error Log view, select the error (do not open it, just select the row), hit Ctrl+C and paste everything (make sure it starts with eclipse.buildId= and that nothing has been cropped) into your question formatted as Sample Code. If more errors have been logged recently, first delete the error log and reproduce your issue.
